# Viewsets: the input field for Tag object does not appear, can not create Dot object with post method

Tags: django-serializer, django-rest-viewsets

Not sure of the reason but maybe I have passed in a wrong way request to the context in views.py, In views.py where post method 'tag' input field is missing

```
    class Dot(models.Model):

        user = models.ForeignKey(
            settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
            on_delete=models.CASCADE       
        )
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        description = models.TextField(max_length=350, blank=True)
        lon = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        lat = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        rating = models.FloatField()
        link = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
        tag = models.ForeignKey('Tag', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
        image = models.ImageField(null=True, upload_to=dot_image_file_path)
```

serializers.py

```
    class TagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

        class Meta:
            model = Tag
            fields = ('id', 'name')
            read_only_fields = ('id',)


    class DotSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

        tag = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

        def get_tag(self, obj):
            queryset = Tag.objects.filter(user=self.context['request'].user)
            return TagSerializer(queryset, many=True).data
        
        class Meta:
            model = Dot
            fields = ('id', 'name', 'description', 'lat', 'lon', 'rating', 'link', 'tag') 
            read_only_fields = ('id',)
```

views.py - appears all input fields except for 'tag'

```
    class DotViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

        serializer_class = serializers.DotSerializer
        queryset = Dot.objects.all()
        authentication_classes = (JWTAuthentication,)
        permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

        def get_queryset(self):
            queryset = self.queryset
            return queryset.filter(user=self.request.user)

        def get_serializer_context(self):
            context = super().get_serializer_context()
            context.update(request=self.request)
            return context
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class DotSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

        tag = TagSerializer()

        def get_tag(self, obj):
            queryset = Tag.objects.filter(user=self.context['request'].user)
            return TagSerializer(queryset, many=True).data
        
        class Meta:
            model = Dot
            fields = ('id', 'name', 'description', 'lat', 'lon', 'rating', 'link', 'tag') 
            read_only_fields = ('id',)
```

Comment: It is not working correctly, when creating Dot thre should be a Tag field to choose option from all available tags, meanwhile now threre is a CharField fot Tag